# How do I troubleshoot WGSI problems with Python and Apache?

Tags: python, django

I inherited a website through my job at the university I go to with about a week or two training on how Django works with Python. Everything has been going well until something randomly broke. I get a 500 Internal Server error on my webpage. So I went to the logs and I'm getting this:

```
[Sun Sep 20 03:40:02 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Sep 20 03:40:02 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Sep 20 03:40:02 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/4.4.10 Python/2.7.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 20 11:13:43 2015] [error] [client 140.118.21.88] mod_wsgi (pid=23683): Target WSGI script '/nfs/mohr/u1/rstone/www/design/apache/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Sep 20 11:13:43 2015] [error] [client 140.118.21.88] mod_wsgi (pid=23683): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/nfs/mohr/u1/rstone/www/design/apache/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Sep 20 11:13:43 2015] [error] [client 140.118.21.88] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Sep 20 11:13:43 2015] [error] [client 140.118.21.88]   File "/nfs/mohr/u1/rstone/www/design/apache/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
[Sun Sep 20 11:13:43 2015] [error] [client 140.118.21.88]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Sep 20 11:13:43 2015] [error] [client 140.118.21.88]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Sep 20 11:13:43 2015] [error] [client 140.118.21.88]     django.setup()
[Sun Sep 20 11:13:43 2015] [error] [client 140.118.21.88]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
```

This is when I realized I know very little about WGSI and how to work with it.

My wgsi.py looks like this:

```
import sys #; raise Exception(sys.path)
import os

path = '/nfs/mohr/u1/rstone/www/design'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

path = '/nfs/mohr/u1/rstone/www/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'design.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Again, all this was working until I came back from a weekend and I was getting the 500 error. I tried moving back to a previous version in git and that didn't work either, so I would assume it's not the code for the website that's breaking it.

If I could just get an idea as to where I should go that would be great. How do I troubleshoot a problem I didn't cause?
Thanks ahead of time for any help I can get with this. I'm still reading as much as I can, but if I can get some advice that would be wonderful.

Comment: django has its own .wsgi that it creates thats all setup ... why arent you using that? (or are you?)

Comment: Odd indeed. I'm assuming you've already tried restarting Apache to restart the daemons? It might help to post the Apache site config file that starts the daemons.